# JAXB force ordering of Sets

Tags: sorting, collections, jaxb, marshalling

I'm marshaling objects which have fields of type Set. The implementation is unsorted, so the order of resulting XML elements is arbitrary, moreover I got a different order every time I do marshaling.

Is there a way to tell marshaller how to sort a field contents during marshaling?

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of a `SortedSet`.  If you initialize an instance of a `Set` on your instance then the JAXB will use that implementation instead of creating a new one:

```
package forum7686859;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    //private Set<String> children = new HashSet<String>();
    private Set<String> children = new TreeSet<String>();

    public Set<String> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<String> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

Comment: No, this is not what I really want. I do NOT want my collection being always sorted, they are unsorted sets by their nature. All I need is to assure the order of elements in XML output is the same for the same collection.